# How to reconstruct original tag

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

Working with lxml and Python. Given an HtmlElement, I'd like to reconstruct the original opening tag used to define it with attributes. For example, if I have an HtmlElement representing `<p id="2" class="some class">content</p>`, I'd like just the string `<p id="2" class="some class">`. I know the whole thing can be turned into a string and processed by regex, but I'd like to see if there's a better way using built in HtmlElement functions.

Tried different attributes and class methods but had no luck. Couldn't make too much sense of the docs. Not sure how `lxml.html.tostring` reconstructs the original tag, but couldn't figure it out looking at the code. I know I can call this tostring function and then use a regex to get the first tag, but I would like this to be simpler / faster.

Comment: So you want just the start tag of an element? Why?

Comment: Writing a parser that has to reconstruct HTML strings after applying transformations sometimes. Tags have to be reconstructed for this operation to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element

def opening_tag(e):
    return "<" + " ".join((e.tag, *(f'{k}="{v}"' for k, v in e.attrib.items()))) + ">"

el = Element("p", attrib={"id": "2", "class": "some class"})

print(opening_tag(el))
# <p id="2" class="some class">
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Does this run into any issues if one of the attributes doesn't have a value? Or are those treated as equivalent in html?

Comment: @erobson That is one of the differences between XML and HTML: XML requires attributes to have values, but in HTML5 boolean attributes may appear without a value. E.g. `<button selected>` is the same `<button selected="">` in HTML5. The value is ignored, only the presence of the attribute is important. If you have attributes without values, the XML parser may fail, so you may want to use the `BeautifulSoup` library in that case.

Comment: The OP is working with lxml, which provides both XML and HTML parsers. ElementTree is for XML only.